# Get data from smart contract interaction before or whitout sending transaction

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a contract with an ABI and I'm currently interacting with it on ropsten network.

I have this function that ask metamask to sign transaction, it's a smart contract interaction and I transfer a NFT token to another address :

```
async function transferToken(index) {
    let address = document.getElementById("inputTransferAddress").value;
    const account = await getCurrentAccount();
    const tx = await MyContract.methods.transfertoken(address, index).send({ from: account })
    }
}
```

Metamask ask me to sign the transaction, and data for this smart contract interaction :

```
GAS FEE 0.000281
etc.

FUNCTION TYPE:Contract Interaction
HEX DATA: 68 BYTES
0x215e2325000000000000000000000000607065f59bdb0cdba95..........000078
```

Is there away to read up this "hex data" without sending them to metamask ?

I want to do it on a FUTURE transaction, because I want to make a scannable QRCODE with a raw transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex data in the question is `data` field that goes to the Ethereun smart contract.:

`transfertoken(address, index)`

- 4 bytes for hash `transfertoken(address,index)` string - choosing which smart contract function is called
- 256 bits (32 bytes) for `address`
- 256 biys (32 bytes) for `index`

You can use ABI encoding and decoding facilities of Web3.js to create the transaction payload yourself, exactly what `methods.xxxx.send` does internally.

However your idea of FUTURE transactions is likely based on false assumptions, because of not understanding how blockchain transactions work. It is easier to make a QR code to go to a web page where user can do a transaction using [WalletConnect link](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking). There is no wallet that supports signing a raw transaction from QR code and your question sounds like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and WalletConnect Link !